# Is it possible to implement Oauth across multiple different servers

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth

I am trying to figure out how (if it's even possible) to implement Google Oauth2 into our platform. Under a normal flow, Oauth would redirect to a set redirect URL and the application would take over with the credentials passed to it.

The problem I am having is all of our customers have their own servers running a version of our application. I'm thinking the only way to implement this would be Saml, but I am curious if there are other ways?

Comment: You can have multiple redirect urls for google auth, but you'll need to whitelist them.

Comment: I thought of that as well, the major issue with that is we have hundreds of customers so it's hard to scale up.

Comment: In that case you can redirect everyone to a central server and from that server to the customer's server. OAuth allows to   set `state` parameter, you can utilize that to store and later on determine the customer you need

Comment: Okay thanks that was sorta the approach I was thinking through but wasn't 100% sure if it would work.

Comment: Glad to be helpful